# Running RoboFramework Test in Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, robotframework, test-runner, robotframework-ide

I managed to write a small script for running a single Robottest in Pycharm.

With Pycharm ->Shift Shift -> External Tools -> Add a new one:

Tool Settings:
Program: "runner.bash"
Working dir: current dir

Arguments: $LineNumber$ $FilePath$

And
runner.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
line=$(/bin/sed -n $1p $2 )
/venv/bin/robot -d results -t "$line" Testfolder
```

You can right-click on the heading a Test and run "external tools" -> "robo runner"

Is it possible to integrate the small green runner icon like it is done for normal code execution left to the line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One Solution is near to that point.
Under [CTRL + ALT + S] Appearance & Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars -> Editor Gutter Pop up -> Add the external command. So the external command is right at the "breakpoint section" context menu.

Comment: You could also assign a keyboard shortcut for your external tool